# Enum index by Value

Tags: c#, enums

```
 [FlagsAttribute]
public enum Colors { Red = 1, Green = 2, Blue = 4, Yellow = 8 };
```

I have an enum as show. I want the ability to get say Colors.Blue is at index 2, index staring from 0.I want to get the index number passing in Colors.Whatever? Can someone post me some snippets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each color uses a single bit as value, you can just locate the index of that bit.

```
public int GetIndex(Colors color) {
   int value = (int)colors;
   int index = 0;
   while (value > 0) {
      value >>= 1;
      index++;
   }
   return index;
}
```

Note that the index of bits is normally zero based, but here you get a one based index.

If you want a zero based index, you would get the index two for blue, not three as you stated in the question. Just start with `index = -1;` if that is the result that you desire.

Comment: sorry for the index, I have now changed it to 2

Answer (score 11):

Try this one:

```
int index  = Array.IndexOf(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Colors )), Colors.Green);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't really understand your question, but is this what you mean:

```
var blue = (Colors)Enum.GetValues(typeof(Colors))[2];
```

Comment: You will get Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Array' ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need it , but one way to do that is

```
 Colors c = (Colors)Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), Enum.GetNames(typeof(Colors))[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest solution I found. Works fine with flags w/o bothering with bytes operations.

```
Array eVals = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
MyEnum eVal = (MyEnum)eVals.GetValue(iIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working after doing it like this:

```
return (Status)Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)).GetValue(this.EvaluationStatusId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code, and it is working:

```
 int index=(int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), "Green");
```